# Joomla - Use LINK URL for menu to show Article

Tags: joomla

i use joomla version 1.5.26
Actually my problem is when i use ALIAS in menu event for show the article, i got this message :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /my-articles.html was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

so i want to change url address to use LINK article url for my Menu event. because when manually i open that LINK url in browser to show the article, it's work
it's possible to change ALIAS become LINK article url in menu configuration?
or mybe some one can help me to figure out that's  error message when i use ALIAS address.. :)

thanks a lot for your helped,,,

Comment: Hi, your question is sort of confusing, could you clarify it with a couple of examples? What is the url when you get the error above? How do you want your links be like?

Comment: in Menu myMenu (in Administrator Joomla website) we have Link and Alias property. The value for Link property is : `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=26` and Alias : `my-articles`
in browser (my Joomla website) when i click menu myMenu, it go to `myjoomla.com/my-articles.html` and i got the error above. When i try to use Link property to open the article like this `myjoomla.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=26` its work.
so if possible, i want to use LINK url for open the article in my joomla website.

Answer (score 2):

OK, 
it is not clear to me how your configuration is set up, but it should contain:

```
var $sef = '1';
var $sef_rewrite = '1';
var $sef_suffix = '1';
```

You also need to activate the .htaccess-file on the server, by renaming it from htaccess.txt to .htaccess (assuming you are on a *nix-server, on windows google the alternative)

Now you should be able to reach menu items by their alias as you explained: http://myjoomla.com/articles.html. Also notice that the url's in the menus should look the same way.

If this fails, there are possible options: 
 - edit the .htaccess-file and set: RewriteBase /
 - edit configuration.php and set var $live_site = 'http://myjoomla.com';

Get back if you still have problems

PS. Would'nt use too much time mucking about in an old Joomla-version like that, consider opgrading to be able to apply security patches etc.